# how to use parameters, including integer, float and string, when using sql in python?

Tags: python, sql, string, parameters, integer

I am trying to use SQL in Python to extract data.

It works fine when it is a simple query like:

```
query="""
      SELECT OBJECTID
      FROM ACTIVITY
      """
a=cursor.execute(query)
```

But when I try to put a number in it, then it will have an error:

[image]

And the same error also happen when i try LIMIT, ROWNUM etc. It looks like I cannot just put a number in the code like this.

I also tried this way:

[image]

But the same error occured.

Also, I tried:

```
query="""
      SELECT TOP %s OBJECTID
      FROM ACTIVITY
      """
num = 5
a=cursor.execute(query, num)
```

But I have got this:

[image]

So, i want to know how to transfer integers, floats and strings into sql in Python like parameters?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: i am using oracle sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think i figure it out. here is the example:

```
query="""
      SELECT OBJECTID,PROJECTOBJECTID
      FROM ACTIVITY
      where ROWNUM<=:num
      """
param={'num':5}
myRow=cursor.execute(query,param)
```

Answer (score 0):

If its the number that is causing the issue, try to use the query this way:

```
query="""
      SELECT TOP %s OBJECTID
      FROM ACTIVITY
      """
num = (5)
a=cursor.execute(query, num)
```

Another way:

```
query="""
          SELECT TOP %(limit)s OBJECTID
          FROM ACTIVITY
          """
param = {
    'limit': 5
}
a=cursor.execute(query, param)
```

Not 100% sure, but this might fix the issue.

Comment: thanks. but it does not work for me. i updated my question. plz take a look

Comment: I added another way. I hope that works, if not, then I will let you know if I find anything else.

Comment: Also, I changed the first approach as well. the num variable should have been a tuple, not an integer. Please try with that change as well once

Comment: hi, thanks. i think i figure it out. using where ROWNUM<=:num, ... param={'num':5} ... myRow=cursor.execute(query,param).